# Scanning through subfolders and testing and specific cel

Tags: vba, excel

Good morning,
I would like to create a code that allowed me to select a folder with a filedialog (selection by filedialog works) and from this folder the code would look for in all subfolders a specific excel file, in this file choose the sheet that interests me. Then for each line of this sheet it was necessary to test the cell "X" if this cell is not empty (that it contains a value) then I copy this line but only the columns F,G,P,Q,X,Y and then paste this in a destination workbook which I would have chosen beforehand. You would find a draft of what I've done
Thank you for help and time

**

```
   Dim Fso As Object
        Dim f1 As Object, f2 As Object
        Dim sh As Excel.Worksheet                   'sh pour sheet
        Dim SourceWB As Excel.Workbook              'WB pour workbook
        Dim DestinationWB As Excel.Workbook
        Dim subf As Variant 'i created a file dialog in a function to let me chose the folder i want
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Long
        Dim SheetCnt As Integer 'sheetcount compteur pour itération, contient le nombre de feuille dans le fichier
        Dim lstRow1 As Long
        Dim lstRow2 As Long
        Dim lstCol As Integer   'last colum, permet de la dernière colonne où l'on possède une donnée
        Dim ws1 As Worksheet
        Private Sub extractionAl_Click()
        With Application
                .DisplayAlerts = False
                .EnableEvents = False
                .ScreenUpdating = False
            End With
        Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set DestinationWB = Application.ThisWorkbook
         lstRow2 = alarmes.Cells(alarmes.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        alarmes.Cells.Range("A2:K" & lstRow2 + 1).ClearContents
        lstRow2 = 2
        For Each f1 In Fso.GetFolder(subf).subfolders
        For Each f2 In f1.Files
            If f2 Like "*indicateur*" Then
        Set SourceWB = Workbooks.Open(f2, ReadOnly:=True)
            For Each sh In SourceWB.Worksheets
                       If sh.Name = "EIF-EIVT-EIPR-EIE mensuelles" Then
                       lstRow1 = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                For i = 1 To lstRow1
                       If sh.Range("X" & i).Value <> "" Then
                'I WANT TO COPY THE LINE BUT ONLY COLUMNS F,G,P,Q,X,Y
                      End If

                       DestinationWB.Activate
                       alarmes.Range("A" & lstRow2).PasteSpecial 'xlPasteValues
                       Application.CutCopyMode = False
                       lstRow2 = alarmes.Cells(alarmes.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

                        End If
               Next sh


          Workbooks(f2.Name).Saved = True

           Workbooks(f2.Name).Close

    End If
Next f2
Next f1
End Sub
```

**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
...
If sh.Range("X" & i).Value <> "" Then
    intersect(sh.rows(i), sh.range("F:G, P:Q, X:Y")).copy _
        destination:=DestinationWB.worksheets("alarmes").cells(lstRow2, "A")
    lstRow2 = lstRow2 + 1
End If
...
```

Comment: Object doesn't support this property or method (Error 438), Office Shared [vblr6.chm1000438]

Comment: That may be due to my inability to determine what alarmes refers to.

Comment: It’s a sheet name in my workbook where I want to paste the values I’ve copied.

Comment: You're using it like a worksheet var or worksheet codename, not a worksheet name. I'll make an adjustment.